# how to create new window / dialog in NON-MFC based app

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to do a trivial thing:

- create main window
- add button to window
- create second window dialog
- once button is pressed, open second window dialog

I see a lot of postings on how to create a new dialog, and how to create a class based on `CDialog`, but whatever I do, VisualStudio complains about `Base class "CDialog" not found in project`. I guess the reason for this is that I'm not using MFC.

Therefore my question: How do I get to open a second window from an existing window. This can't be that hard, right?

**EDIT** I'm using the standard win32 windows programming api.

Comment: You can use `CreateWindow` again.

Comment: More interesting than which Framework you don't use is which framework you DO use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty comfortable way of creating dialogs is to use [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net/) which is free and has a small footprint. It allows you to window programming after just including the headers.